# Error: cannot resolve module 'ballerina/sql'

Tags: ballerina

I am using [JDBC Client CRUD Operations](https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/jdbc-client-crud-operations.html) in my project with ballerina 1.0.0 alpha version. Below is the my code.

```
import ballerina/io;
import ballerinax/jdbc;
import ballerina/sql;


jdbc: Client testDB = new({
        url: "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/incidentReportingSys",
        username: "root",
        password: "",
        poolOptions: { maximumPoolSize: 5 },
        dbOptions: { useSSL: false }
});
```

Then I get the errors `cannot resolve module 'ballerinax/jdbc'` and `cannot resolve module 'ballerina/sql'`.

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JDBC connector name is changed to `java.jdbc` hence you can import it as

```
import ballerinax/java.jdbc;
```

You can find a sample here [Ballerina JDBC example](https://github.com/ballerina-platform/ballerina-lang/blob/cb61e3d8c8e583bf980dfc1d21bfb4961fc70a3b/examples/jdbc-client-crud-operations/jdbc_client_crud_operations.bal#L2).

Comment: Are documentations for ballerina-1.0.0 not updated yet?

Comment: Documentation rewriting is in progress hence website is not updated. You can find the Ballerina by examples in the Ballerina repo.